# Factory of union type without type casting

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

```
abstract class Passenger {
    passengerKey: string;
}

class PassengerAdult extends Passenger {
    adultField: string;
}

class PassengerInfant extends Passenger {
    infantField: string;
}

class PassengerFactory {
    static createPassenger(isInfant: boolean): PassengerAdult | PassengerInfant {
        if (isInfant) {
            return new PassengerInfant();
        }

        return new PassengerAdult();
    }
}

const passengerInfant: PassengerInfant = PassengerFactory.createPassenger(true);
```

I get an error that

> Type 'PassengerAdult | PassengerInfant' is not assignable to type
>   'PassengerInfant'.   Type 'PassengerAdult' is not assignable to type
>   'PassengerInfant'.
>       Property 'infantField' is missing in type 'PassengerAdult'.

Can I in some way force typescript to understand what he's returning inside `createPassenger` method? I know that in the call line I'd cast the result like

`const passengerInfant: PassengerInfant = <PassengerInfant>PassengengerFactory...`

but i'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can describe return type that depends on literal value with overload declarations. You need to add all three declarations for `createPassenger` because the implementation signature does not participate in overload resolution - without the third declararation the call with non-literal value would not compile.

```
class PassengerFactory {
    static createPassenger(isInfant: false): PassengerAdult;
    static createPassenger(isInfant: true): PassengerInfant;
    static createPassenger(isInfant: boolean): PassengerAdult | PassengerInfant;
    static createPassenger(isInfant: boolean): PassengerAdult | PassengerInfant {
        if (isInfant) {
            return new PassengerInfant();
        }

        return new PassengerAdult();
    }
}

const passengerInfant: PassengerInfant = PassengerFactory.createPassenger(true);
const passengerRandom: Passenger = PassengerFactory.createPassenger(Math.random() > 0.5);
```

**update** here is complete example that gives the error for the last line: "Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'.":

```
abstract class Passenger {
    passengerKey: string;
}

class PassengerAdult extends Passenger {
    adultField: string;
}

class PassengerInfant extends Passenger {
    infantField: string;
}

class PassengerFactory {
    static createPassenger(isInfact: false): PassengerAdult;
    static createPassenger(isInfant: true): PassengerInfant;
    static createPassenger(isInfant: boolean): PassengerAdult | PassengerInfant {
        if (isInfant) {
            return new PassengerInfant();
        }

        return new PassengerAdult();
    }
}

const passengerInfant: PassengerInfant = PassengerFactory.createPassenger(true);
const passengerRandom: Passenger = PassengerFactory.createPassenger(Math.random() > 0.5);
```

Comment: Actually it did compile without the third declaration (at least in typescript playground). Really interesting concept. Will I find more information about that in typescript documentation?

Comment: The last paragraph on this [page says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads): "Note that the function pickCard(x): any piece is not part of the overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object and one that takes a number. Calling pickCard with any other parameter types would cause an error." I added complete example that gives an error. But if you only will call `createPassenger` with literals `true` and `false` then indeed the third overload is not necessary.

Comment: FYI, you can avoid writing 3 overloads using conditional types `static createPassenger<T extends boolean >(isInfant: T): T extends true? PassengerAdult : PassengerInfant` this works because `boolean ` is seen by the compiler as a union `true |false` and conditional types distribute over unions.

Comment: Seems quite nice but would be useful when we deal with not 2 but 3-4-5 return types. But actually I can't make it works using typescript playground. It doesn't compile.